# Length property in immutable objects

Tags: c#, performance

If object is immutable (my own implemented object) should I use property for Length or just readonly variable? If object has Length as property, it loses some performance in for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myObject.Length; i++) // Length is readonly variable
{
    // some code
}
```

and:

```
int len = myObject.Length; // Length is a property

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    // some code
}
```

What do you suggest?

Comment: Have you measured that the property causes a loss in performance? `get`ters are usually simple enough to be inlined by the JIT compiler, so there will be no performance difference between a field and a property.

Comment: Job: erase memory using byte* with for loop. Using variable from object = X ms. Using property = 2*X ms. So property is alot slower. When I copy Length to local variable (from object variable) it gives another 10% speed. So finally I use Length property, then copy its value to local variable before each for loop. Ofcourse when I use long* to clear that memory, It will be even more useful to copy Length to local variable. So I solved it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way that it matters in a sample like that. The likelihood of the JIT not inling a simple `get` is very low. Even if the `get` is not inlined, the extra function call is not going to be your performance bottleneck outside of very simple code.

To show what I mean I ran the following in Release mode (if you leave it debug it will work differently).

```
private int Length { get; set; }
private int _length;
void Run()
{
    Length = int.MaxValue;
    _length = int.MaxValue;
    var watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    watch.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < _length; i++)
    {
    }
    watch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Elapsed: {0}ms", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}
```

I ran it 10 times and got the following averages: 743 ms for Property, 740 ms for Variable. That difference is probably just because of the low number of attempts and other things happening on my machine.

Now if you turn off inlining via an attribute you will get a difference in time: 4577 ms for Property and 775 ms for Variable. Now that sounds like a huge difference (6x as much time total) but keep in mind my loop condition: 2 billion iterations. That means that the difference was something like 2 ns per operation. In other words around 4 clock cycles, not enough to worry about in all but the most extreme performance scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some special dataset here which is very big, so you expect to do a huge number of iterations of the loop, the difference between a property and a variable will probably be negligible.

The simple option is to go with a variable. Using a property will give you the added benefit of being able to modify it's behavior later without changing the signature of your class (for instance if you want to calculate the length in some new way).

Another related benefit might be the ability to set a property privately (change it at a later time if needed), but only read it publicly.

I suppose I would go for a property for these reasons. In any case, I would not make this choice based only on expected effects on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Change temporary variable to query is a pretty standard refactor.  In other words, it is strongly suggested that if the property call is very fast, then you shouldn't create a temporary variable.  It is called 'replaceTempWithQuery'.  Here is a blurb on it:

http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceTempWithQuery.html

I would strongly recommend the book refactoring to everyone that does programming.

Adding as an EDIT:  I got downvoted for this, but premature optimization is really something to avoid - I would only recommend fixing a query with a temp if it produces very noticeable problems.

[A famous quote from Donald Knuth: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization).  Regardless, it is a matter of choice, unless you will have lots of maintainers of your code.  Then, time in maintenance often has a major impact on your optimization/design choices.